# I need a config/local_override.yml file in Symfony2 but need to merge params

Tags: php, symfony

I want to be able to include a *config/local_override.yml* file in Symfony2 that isn't submitted to version control that can be used locally for testing and overriding any part of the config.

I have done this in *config/config.yml*:

```
imports:
    - { resource: local_override.yml }
```

and can then include things like this in *local_override.yml*:

```
parameters:
  parameter1: 'new value'
```

However if the original value in one of the config files is something like this:

```
parameters:
  abc_config:
    option1: 123
    option2: 'test'
    option3: true
```

and if I then do this in *local_override.yml*:

```
parameters:
  abc_config:
    option2: 'new value'
```

then it clears all other values set (option1 and option3).

Is there a better way to do this and merge those values together?

This isn't just to override the database configuration, but any parameter.

The idea is to simply override any part of the config when testing locally, but not touch the main config files. That way I can have my codebase in the remote repository and pull it to a live public server to use - but also have developers pull to their local machine and use the override file to change any part of the config that they need to for dev/testing.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/master/app/config